# Camel is removing content of file after move it

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, apache-camel

I have a spring boot application with camel and I try to move a file from a server using FTP to my local machine, my problem is that the file is empty after move it,

This is my class that extends the RouteBuilder class:

```
public class Controlador extends RouteBuilder{
    @Autowired
    private ArchivoBS archivoBS;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("ftp://user@host:21?password=pass&passiveMode=true&delete=true").convertBodyTo(InputStream.class).process(archivoBS).to("file:C:\\Users\\juan.gaytan\\Desktop\\prueba2");
    }
}
```

My class ArchivoBS implements the Processor interface:

```
@Service
public class ArchivoBS implements Processor{
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {

        InputStream fis = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String strLinea;

        while ((strLinea = br.readLine()) != null) {

        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to solve my issue?,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of file is it? Text File? Binary File?

Comment: Hi namphibian, the file is a .txt

Comment: One thing that I can think is that you're closing the InputStream on the process method, then when you're saving to file later with Apache Camel it's already closed, so, no content. But I don't know if you can just leave InputStream opened... But do the test please.

Comment: Yeah Raphael is on something. See also this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: In addition to what @ClausIbsen is saying, perhaps you're modifying the exchange payload in your processor. Can you show its entire implementation? Obviously anonymize anything sensitive before.

Comment: Hi @Morfic I read the link you provided, let me try with the .streamCaching() method, I edited my question but as you can see I'm reading the inputstream and the camel documentation says that it can only be read once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ClausIbsen that provided this link  http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html, I changed configure method and now looks like this:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("ftp://user@host:21?password=pass&passiveMode=true&delete=true").streamCaching().convertBodyTo(InputStream.class).process(archivoBS).to("file:C:\\Users\\juan.gaytan\\Desktop\\prueba2");
}
```

I only needed to add the .streamCaching() method and it worked perfectly, hope this help someone else.